# Force git to mark line as deleted and re-added

Tags: git

If at one point I were to commit a file that included the following code:

```
if(x)
{
    //do something
}
```

And then later decide that what I actually needed was this:

```
while(x)
{
    //do something else
}
```

Git would correctly detect that I removed two lines and added two lines.  However, at least sometimes, I think it would be helpful (e.g. for readability) to ask git to treat the two lines that did not change as if they had.

I know that I could add a white space or something else to the lines that didn't need to change, but in real life situations, this would often be a lot of work (and I don't want pointless trailing white spaces, anyway).

Update 1:

At first I was thinking that I could delete all four lines, commit the change, add the four new lines and commit again, but after [axiac's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) comment, I'm realizing that would not accomplish what I want.

Update 2:

Responding to [0x5453's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282436/0x5453) comment, I tried a `git diff` with each of the four diff algorithms that git offers, and each of them behave similarly in this case.

Now that I'm thinking in terms of algorithms, I guess I'm hoping for an algorithm that attempts to identify when a whole block of code has changed and can treat lines with brackets as part of that code block even when a new code block has some identical lines, but I'm open to another approach if it gets the job done.

Comment: Git does not store differences but snapshots. It stores the file as is in each commit and computes the difference when it needs it (for `git diff`, for merges/rebases/cherry picks etc.)

Comment: To expand on @axiac's comment, the specific diff behavior can be controlled via the [`diff.algorithm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#Documentation/diff-config.txt-diffalgorithm) config option or by passing certain [args](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---minimal) to `git diff`.

Comment: Git is a versioning system, and as such does not need to understand "code" or "anything". What you are looking for is a tool that can parse code, understand what a "class", "function" or "block" is and highlight differences there.

I guess you can accomplish that with git hooks and some additional script. Something that gets executed after commit and, parsing code and diffs, prints a report of changed "classes", "blocks", "functions"... Maybe [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ask Git for a diff, either using `git diff` or another tool, such as `git format-patch`, you're asking it to produce some set of changes that goes from the first input (the preimage) to the second input (the image), and Git can use any algorithm it likes to do that.

Technically, it would be a valid diff to simply delete all the lines from the preimage and add all the ones from the image, but that leads to diffs which are less useful because they are hard to read.  Git does have different algorithms, such as patience and histogram, that *often* produce better diffs, but there will still be some cases where they produce bad diffs, or diffs which are worse than the default algorithm (myers).

Your proposed change might result in more readable diffs in some cases, but it might also lead to confusion because users might wonder why the lines with the braces changed, when in fact they did not.  There is almost certainly no perfect diff algorithm because there is no universal heuristic for how code is to be written (for example, C has many brace and indentation styles, and that's just one of hundreds of languages) and determining what is legible is highly subjective.

In any case, you may find that some diffs will be hard to read, and while that is unfortunate, it's simply something to accept.  I had such a case with a change I made recently, and I had to simply inform my colleagues that it was easier to think of the change differently than the diff showed.  In short, I don't think there's an option in Git to do what you want, and I doubt that you're going to find a nice diff algorithm to add to Git that works like you want.